# Connotation of "faire son mieux"

Tags: sens, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

Could the locution "faire son mieux" convey a negative connotation depending on the context? If so, I would like to see a couple of sentences showing that it is used in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been some controversy in the chat while discussing about whether *faire **de** son mieux* has a negative connotation or not.

In my opinion, the key word is the possessive here: ***mon** mieux*, ***ton** mieux*, ***son** mieux*, ***leur** mieux*...

It emphasizes the fact someone's best is not ***the** best* but a personal upper limit that is not pushed by them.

> *Je ne suis pas à tout moment ce que je devrais être. Je fais de mon mieux, alors que très souvent je pourrais faire mieux que mon mieux.*
> Marguerite Yourcenar, *Les yeux ouverts*, 1980.

> *Parfois, nous pouvons prononcer des mots avec des bonnes intentions mais les formulations maladroites peuvent aboutir à l’inverse du résultat souhaité. C’est le cas avec la formule “fais de ton mieux”.* Caroline, [Apprendre, réviser, mémoriser.](https://apprendre-reviser-memoriser.fr/fais-de-ton-mieux-enfants/), 2018

> *Un professeur qui dit d'un élève "il fait de son mieux" ne vole pas très haut dans le registre des louanges.* Inconnu, [Etudes littéraires](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/discussion/12318/faire-de-son-mieux).

> *"La situation est difficile, il fait de son mieux." C'est ainsi que Dominique Strauss-Kahn évoque l'action de François Hollande*, [L'Express](https://www.lexpress.fr/actualite/politique/pour-dsk-hollande-fait-de-son-mieux-face-a-une-situation-difficile_1265261.html), 2013

> *Mais Massimo Furlan, ou plutôt la créature qu'il convoque pour l'occasion, Pino Tozzi, est d'une certaine manière incompétent : il ne parle ni portugais ni finlandais, ne chante pas très bien, même s'il fait de son mieux, après de nombreuses répétitions.* [Festival d'avignon](https://festival-avignon.com/fr/edition-2010/programmation/1973-23172). 2010

> *Arrivé sur ce Tour de France avec l'ambition de faire de son mieux mais sans penser une seule seconde qu'il pourrait le gagner dès sa première participation*, [Cyclism'Actu](https://www.cyclismactu.net/news-tour-de-france-tadej-pogacar-j-ai-attaqu-comme-un-fou-socialnetwork-94696.html), 2020

This is why I consider that this expression has at least a slight negative connotation because under the hood it is condescending and says: *I'm/you are/they are not able to do better*.

What would have had an always positive connotation is:

> *Tu as bien fait.* You did well.

> *Tu as réussi.* You succeeded.

or even better:

> *Tu t'es surpassé.* You outdone yourself.

On the other hand, *tu as fait de ton mieux* might still be considered as a mildly positive expression when used to comfort someone after a failure.

> *Ne sois pas déçu de n'avoir terminé que sixième, tu as fait de ton mieux.* Don't be disappointed only getting the sixth place, you did your best.

Stronger negative sentences would be:

> *Tu n'as pas fait de ton mieux.*  You "under-performed".

> *Tu n'as pas bien fait.* You didn't do well.

Answer (score 4):

« Faire son mieux » n'est pas exact ; il faut toujours écrire « faire **de** son mieux » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_de_son_mieux)).
C'est une locution qui n'est pas absolument figée. L'adjectif possessif s'accorde et le verbe se conjugue.

Non, cette locution n'a pas de connotations négatives. Cependant, elle est utilisée dans des contextes où la personne ou les personnes qui font de leur mieux ne font pas nécessairement quelque chose de très bon ou de très bien comme elle peut aussi s'employer dans ces contexte où c'est tout le contraire.

On voit d'après les exemples du Wiktionnaire que le verbe peut avoir un complément.

> - Sois donc attentif, mon garçon ; sois docile ; *fais de ton mieux* **ce que tu dois faire**. Dans la vie, tout est là ! — (Hector Malot, Sans famille, 1878)
> - Quand je fus assuré que le silence était bien revenu, je saisis un canif et *fis de mon mieux* **pour tenter de m’entailler la jambe droite**. Mais la lame était émoussée et je manquais de cœur à l’ouvrage. — (Graham Greene, Une sorte de vie, traduit de l'anglais par Georges Belmont & Hortense Chabrier, éd. Robert Laffont, 1971, chapitre 3, §. 1)S

Dans le premier exemple le verbe a un COD (ce que tu dois faire), dans le second c'est un CC de but (pour tenter de m’entailler la jambe droite).

*En plus des exemples du Wiktionnaire*

- Il **a fait de son mieux** mais ce n'est pas suffisant.
- Il vous sera demandé de **faire de votre mieux**.
- Les peintres **ont fait de leur mieux** et leur travail peut être considéré comme irréprochable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115898/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-connotation-of-faire-son-mieux).

Answer (score 3):

*Faire de son mieux* sous-entend une obligation de moyens, pas de résultats.

Lorsque le donneur d'ordre s'attend à un résultat, il peut considérer que *faire de son mieux* est insuffisant. Il préfèrera alors choisir un autre prestataire qui garantit les résultats.

Answer (score 1):

C'est une expression *subjective* qui exprime une certaine indécision, sans doute à cause d'une issue incertaine. Sinon, on emploierait des expressions similaires comme *faire au mieux* ou *faire pour le mieux*.

Comment: Non, c'est une expression qui exprime simplement que la personne ou l'entité qui a fait de son mieux a utilisé le meilleur de ses possibilités, a fait l'effort maximum qu'elle pouvait se permettre dans la tâche  ou l'activité mentionnée. Il n'y a rien de subjectif. Que l'effort ait eu du succès ou pas est une autre question. Lire par exemple ceci, il y en a des quantités comme cela : https://books.google.fr/books?id=BQIbW9rOlPkC&pg=PA25&dq=%22fait+de+son+mieux%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFo5PrlOjsAhUz8uAKHc92BVYQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22fait%20de%20son%20mieux%22&f=false (1/2)

Comment: Lisez le paragraphe en entier. Vous verrez que « faire pour le mieux », qui y est utilisé, signifie quasiment la même chose. (2/2)

Comment: LPH: C'est subjectif dans le sens où tous (ou les personnes en présence) n'ont pas les même ressentis ou perceptions.

Comment: Ce n'est pas subjectif du tout : quand le narrateur dit de son caractère qu'il/elle a fait de son mieux il s'agit d'un jugement objectif qui permet à tout le monde de conclure que le caractère s'est comporté au mieux de ses possibilités. Même lorsque quelqu'un affirme qu'i a fait de son mieux il n'y a aucune subjectivité : avant d'avoir prouvé que quelqu'un est coupable on ne peut pas présumer sa culpabilité ; le principe est le même, vous pouvez douter mais pas plus. Comprenez-vous que votre explication à propos de « pour le mieux » ne tient pas ?

Comment: @LPH: Votre propos est vraiment diffus : de (mon, ton, son, notre, votre, leur) mieux, cela n'est pas équivalent. De même, les expressions *faire au mieux*, *faire pour le mieux*, *faire de son mieux* **ne sont pas** équivalentes.

Comment: Donc votre assertion à propos de « pour le mieux » est correcte ?

Comment: La nuance que je perçois entre *faire pour le mieux* et *faire de son mieux* est la suivante: *faire pour le mieux/au mieux* signifie "essayer d'atteindre le meilleur résultat possible dans les circonstances extérieures  données" et *faire de son mieux* signifie "essayer d'atteindre le meilleur résultat possible compte tenu de ses capacités personnelles". Dans ce sens, "de son mieux" dépendra de *qui* est supposé *faire*, ce qui n'est pas le cas dans *faire pour le mieux*.

Comment: Il y a bien une nuance, et on peut faire pour le mieux sans faire de son mieux. Cependant, faire pour le mieux n'est pas du tout incompatible avec faire de son mieux comme on peut faire les deux et que le plus souvent, lorsqu'on a fait pour le mieux on a aussi fait de son mieux.